# Output text into nearest element using Jquery in ERB view context

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is what I need:

```
<dd class="data-list__value">
  5
</dd>
```

The number will depend on whether or not a checkbox is checked. Here is my approach. I have tried it with and without the `.closest('dd')` and `.html()`, as you can see.

**Neither results in any text on the actual page.**

```
  <dd class="data-list__value">
    <script>
    if ($('#verified').prop('checked') == true) {
      $(this).closest('dd').html('5');
    } else {
      "5";
    }
    </script>
  </dd>
```

What an I doing wrong?

**Solution:**

```
    <% @styles.each do |style| %>
      <dd class="data-list__value" id="scores_<%= style.id %>">
        <script>
        if ($('#verified').prop('checked') == true) {
          $('#scores_<%= style.id %>').append('<%= style.reviews.count %>');
        } else {
          $('#scores_<%= style.id %>').append('<%= style.verified_review_count %>');
        }
        </script>
      </dd>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: if you put script tag inside a tag, it will never identify the tag as 'this'

Comment: well is there a way to just output the text into the view.. without having to assign it to a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest moving the js to an external file or at least to the bottom of the page and do something like this...

```
if ($('#verified').prop('checked') == true) {
  $('.data-list__value').html('5');
}else{
  $('.data-list__value').html('some other value');
}
```

If there are multiple tags with this class you can use .first() or last() or by the index of the array.

Are you able to use an id on this?

```
$('#checkedValue').html('5');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it helps, it's just more than I really wanted to do.. ugh. I wish they made it easier.. I guess it just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you mean, i think thats it:

```
<script>
    $('#verified').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.data-list__value').text('4');
        } else {
            $('.data-list__value').text('5');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/G4L6u/

Comment: Good work, basically this works for one, but I had a bunch of dds to fill in.. See my answer above, and thanks for your help!

Comment: if you have more than one, you cant use the same ID for each one.. you cant repeat ID in your code. If you need it to more then one dd, you should correct your question and your code.

Comment: There we go. All fixed up